# How to begin using the cron job in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2, cron-task

i want to send an email at a specific time of the day ( 9am ).

I saw that i have to use cron jobs. I saw a lot of different things how to work with this, but it seems really difficult. Can somebody explain to me how to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific problem do you have? If you don't know how to create a CLI task, then you probably looking for Zend\Console component.

Comment: That's also a possibility. I actually don't know what i have to use to accomplish this. It has to send an email automatically to the users of the website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a MailController with an sendMailAction() inside the app/root module.
2. Add a console route to your app/root module's module.config.php:

> array('router' => array(
>               'routes' => array(..)),
>
> ```
> 'console' => array(
>     'router' => array(
>         'routes' => array(
>             'cronroute' => array(
>                 'options' => array(
>                     'route'    => 'sendemail',
>                     'defaults' => array(
>                         'controller' => 'Root\Controller\Console',
>                         'action' => 'sendemail'
>                     )
>                 )
>             )
>         )
>     )
> )
> );
> ```

1. Execute this in Terminal

   $ cd product path php public/index.php sendemail

Comment: Can this be done automatically ? without me doing something in the Terminal ?

Comment: Depending on your hoster there cronjob services/programms/GUI's available.